# Prevent files from opening with the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When you close VS with project files open, the next time you open that solution, it opens the same files.

Is there a way to prevent this?  Currently I try to remember to close all the open tabs before I exit.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .suo file in the solution directory :D

Comment: That was not the answer I was looking for, but it did lead me to another post with a good solution.  So thanks :)